# Java Swing - Show border of controls when clicking Tab key only

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I have noticed this behavior in most programs :

1. When clicking any control in a window no border appears around this control, like here :
   [image]
2. When clicking 'Tab' key a border appears around the control, then i can navigate through all controls, like here :
   [image]

But in Java Swing applications the border appears when click on the control and also when clicking the 'Tab' key, or i can hide that border forever.

**Is there a way to use the default behavior mentioned above(Show the border when clicking 'Tab' key only) ?**

Answer (score 0):

public void setFocusPainted(boolean b) ?

Actually it depends on L&F. E.g. the code

```
    protected void paintFocus(Graphics g, Rectangle textRect, Dimension d){
    g.setColor(getFocusColor());
    BasicGraphicsUtils.drawDashedRect(g, textRect.x, textRect.y, textRect.width, textRect.height);
}
```

from WindowsRadioButtonUI (checkbox UI extends radiobutton UI)